# jnats 2.4.2 hangs on shutdown

Tags: java, nats.io

When runnung a Java NATS client like the one below with jnats 2.4.1, everything is fine. When updating to jnats 2.4.2, the shutdown takes approx. one minute after printing "finished":

```
import io.nats.client.Connection;
import io.nats.client.Nats;
import java.time.Duration;

public class Tryout {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection con = Nats.connect();
        con.drain(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        System.out.println("finished");
    }
}
```

My environment: I'm running things from IntelliJ IDEA with an SBT build on a Windows 10 machine with Java 11.0.2.

Is this a bug in 2.4.2, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in jnats 2.4.3, see https://github.com/nats-io/java-nats/issues/227.

Great to see it fixed & new version released within a couple of days!